# Prolog - multiplying by addition

Tags: prolog

I need simple fuction in SWI-prolog which multiplying by addition. Something like m(X,Y,Z) where for example X=5, Z=3 <==> 5*3. Y is result: Y=5, Y=10, Y=15 [stop]. I was thinking about something like that:

```
m(X,Y,Z):- Z>0, /*when Z reaches 0 you stop */ I=X+X, W=Z-1, m(I,Y,W).
```

But it always return "false" and dunno why.

Comment: `addiction` really?

Comment: @GuyCoder: an addiction to Prolog of course :)

Comment: Rather start using [tag:successor-arithmetics]!

Comment: It returns false because it continues to call itself until `Z` goes to zero, then it fails since `Z > 0` no longer succeeds. There is no success case. Where did you tell Prolog what the rule is for `Z = 0` case?

Comment: You probably want `I is X+X, W is Z-1` instead of using `=/2` (which means _unify_, not assign).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start by thinking about what the predicate should describe: it's a relation between three numbers, where the third is the product of the first two. Since you want to describe multiplication by reducing the second argument to zero while adding up the first accordingly many times we are talking about natural numbers. So a nicely descriptive name would be nat_nat_prod/3. Next consider the possible cases:

1. The second argument can be zero. Then the product has to be zero as well since X*0=0. So this is the base case.
2. Otherwise the second argument is greater than zero. Then you want to decrement it by one and calculate the product of the first argument and this new number. Since the predicate can use itself to describe that, this is a recursive goal. Subsequently you add the first argument to the intermediary product described by the recursion.

This can be written in Prolog like so:

```
nat_nat_prod(_X,0,0).         % case 1)
nat_nat_prod(X,Y1,P1) :-      % case 2)
   Y1 > 0,
   Y0 is Y1-1,
   nat_nat_prod(X,Y0,P0),
   P1 is P0+X.
```

Now let's try some queries:

```
?- nat_nat_prod(5,3,P).
P = 15 ;
false.

?- nat_nat_prod(5,4,P).
P = 20 ;
false.

?- nat_nat_prod(5,0,P).
P = 0 ;
false.

?- nat_nat_prod(1,0,P).
P = 0 ;
false.

?- nat_nat_prod(1,1,P).
P = 1 ;
false.
```

However, when playing around with the predicate, you'll notice that the first two arguments have to be instantiated otherwise you'll get an error:

```
?- nat_nat_prod(1,Y,3).
ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
?- nat_nat_prod(X,1,3).
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

This happens due to the use of >/2 and is/2. You could get around this problem by using CLP(FD) but I think that's beside the point. This way of defining multiplication is obviously very inefficient compared to using the standard arithmetic function */2, e.g.:

```
?- time(nat_nat_prod(2,1000000,P)).
% 3,000,000 inferences, 33.695 CPU in 33.708 seconds (100% CPU, 89035 Lips)
P = 2000000 ;
% 3 inferences, 0.031 CPU in 0.031 seconds (100% CPU, 97 Lips)
false.

?- time(P is 2*1000000).
% 1 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (86% CPU, 82325 Lips)
P = 2000000.
```

As already hinted by @false in the comments it is more common to introduce people to [successor arithmetics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/successor-arithmetics) first and then to define addition/multiplication of two numbers in s(X) notation this way. Since you can't use the standard arithmetic functions with s(X) numbers, you also don't run into the associated instantiation errors.

Comment: By using an accumulator the code could be tail recursive, which gives ~100X speedup! As use(ful|less) as before, but faster;)

Comment: @repeat: You are absolutely right about that. However, my thinking was that the predicate's non-relational behaviour due to instantiation errors is the actual downside here. And I use the speed argument only to point out why I'm not throwing CLP(FD) at it to solve that issue. A 100x speedup would not really change that, it would only shift my axample query from 1000000 to 100000000 ;-)

Comment: @repeat: I actually wrote a tail recursive version as well, so I can confirm the speedup by factor 100, however, since that consists of a calling predicate with 3 arguments and the actual predicate with an additional argument I opted to post the shorter code. Do you think I should post the tail recursive version?

Comment: Also, I wouldn’t worry too much about runtime! I wrote the comment because I was a bit surprised by 100X: I expected something like 10X or 20X... I shall repeat the experiment with [tag:sicstus-prolog] ;)

Comment: @repeat: I just tried it with YAP and I get speedup factors around 12 to 14. I'm curious what you'll find with SICStus...

Comment: Does your YAP have a JIT? SICStus does, so I’m keen on finding out how much it rocks... so far the SICStus JIT has always left me **very** impressed.

Comment: @repeat: None that I'm aware of. Unless you mean just in time indexing. That it has (see e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3896)).

Comment: Ok, 'shallow' indexing on one (or several) clause terms is quite common among different Prolog processors---even though each one appears to have its own strengths/weaknesses... actual generation of assembly code is not so widespread. Sad!